# Парсинг XML с помощью JQuery.

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlparser, парсер, javascript

Доброго времени суток. При парсинге XML не могу правильно вывести полученные элементы в таблицу. Есть XML:

```
<group>
 <title_h-1>Стены</title_h-1>
 <itog>Итого по стенам и перегородкам</itog>
 <h-2>
  <title_h-2>Демонтажные работы</title_h-2>
  <item>
   <name>Очистка стен от обоев</name>
   <measure>кв.м</measure>
   <volume></volume>
   <cost placeholder="от 50 руб."></cost>
   <sum></sum>
  </item>
  <item>
   <name>...</name>
   <measure>...</measure>
   <volume>...</volume>
   <cost placeholder="от 70 руб.">...</cost>
   <sum>...</sum>
 </h-2>
 <h-2>
  <title_h-2>Отделочные работы</title_h-2>
  <item>
   ...
  </item>
 </h-2>
</group>
<group>
 ...
</group>
```

JavaScript (var $table == XML):

```
var group = 1;
var type = 1;
var item = 1;
var JSection = $($table).find('price');
var $group = JSection.children();
$group.each(function(){
 var h_1 =  $(this).children('title_h-1').text();
 var itog = $(this).children('itog').text();
 $('<tbody><tr id="name_'+ group +'"><th colspan="5" class="h-1">'+ h_1 +'</th></tr><tr><th class="add_new">Наименование работ</th><th>Ед.изм</th><th class="qty">Количество</th><th>Цена</th><th class="cost">Стоимость работ</th></tr>').appendTo('#price');
 $(this).children('h-2').each(function(){
  var h_2 =  $(this).children('title_h-2').text();
  $('<tr id="type_'+ type +'"><th colspan="5" class="h-2">'+ h_2 +' <i class="icon-plus-sign" title="Добавить новый пункт"></i></th></tr>').appendTo('#price');;
  $(this).children('item').each(function(){
   var name = $(this).children('name').text();
   var measure = $(this).children('measure').text();
   var volume = $(this).children('volume').text();
   var placeholder = $(this).children('cost').attr('placeholder');
   var cost = $(this).children('cost').text();
   var sum = $(this).children('sum').text();
   $('<tr id="item_'+ item +'"><td class="name">'+ name +'</td><td class="measure">'+ measure +'</td><td class="volume"><input type="text" class="amt" value="'+ volume +'" /></td><td class="cost"><input type="text" class="value" placeholder="'+ placeholder +'" value="'+ cost +'" /></td><td class="result">'+ sum +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#price');;
   group++;
   type++;
   item++;
  });
 });
 $('<tr id="itog_'+ group +'"><th colspan="4" class="align_r">'+ itog +'</th><th class="itog"></th></tr></tbody>').appendTo('#price');;
});
```

И, собственно, HTML:

```
 <table id="price"></table>
```

На выходе первый <tbody> содержит все остальные элементы контейнеров <item>. Я так понимаю, что это происходит из-за использования .append(). А как сделать правильно, под утро, не могу понять.

Comment: Вот демка для наглядности: [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/JrZGd/).  
«Транспортные и накладные расходы» должны содержать строки согласно структуре XML. Вместо этого они просто выводятся в конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы аппендите не закрытый тег tbody. Он закрывается автоматически и из-за этого и плывет вся верстка. А тот закрывающий тег, который аппендится в конце просто игнорируется. Аппендить нужно логически завершенные, html-валидные блоки. В вашем случае просто добавьте в начало цикла строку

```
$('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo('#price');
```

и уберите открывающий и закрывающий тег tbody. [Вот немного переделал Ваш пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/JrZGd/2/)

А вообще, откровенно говоря, не самый лучший кусок кода. Советую поработать над его оптимизацией.

Comment: Безмерно благодарен. Не знал про эту особенность «append'а».

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Comment: Нет, XML уже приведен в строковый тип.